# Passing variables to sftp batch

Tags: bash, shell, sftp

I'm writing a script that needs to pass a variable to the sftp batch. I have been able to get some commands working based on other documentation I've searched out, but can't quite get to what I need.

The end-goal is to work similar to a file test operator on a remote server:
 `( if [-f $a ] then:; else exit 0;)`

Ultimately, I want the file to continue running the script if the file exists (:), or exit 0 if it does NOT exist (not exit 1). The remote machine is a **Windows** server, not Linux.

Here's what I have:

NOTE - the variable I'm trying to pass, `$source_dir`, changes based on the input parameter of the script that calls this function. This and the `ls` wildcard is the tricky part. I have been able to make it work when looking for a specific file, but not just "any" file.

```
    ${source_dir}= /this/directory/changes

    RemoteCheck () {

    /bin/echo "cd $source_dir" > someBatch.txt
    /bin/echo "ls *" >> someBatch.txt

    /usr/bin/sftp -b testBatch.txt -oPort=${sftp_port} ${sftp_ip}


    exit_code=$?;
    if [ $exit_code -eq 0 ]; then
        :
    else
        exit 0
    fi
```

There may be a better way to do this, but I have searched multiple forums and have not yet found a way to manipulate this.

Any help is appreciated, you gurus have always been very helpful!

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to `cd $source_dir`? In your code you overwrite it with `ls *`.

Comment: what do you mean I overwrite it? Doesn't it do the commands consecutively? I may not be using this correctly - but I thought I could string several commands together like this and they will execute in the order?

Comment: @alvits - I see what you mean. I kind of stumbled back across this and edited the redirectors to match. This was my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot test for existence of any file using just exit code of the OpenSSH `sftp`.

You can redirect the `sftp` output to a file and parse it to see if there are any files.

You can use shell `echo` command to delimit the listing from the rest of the output like:

```
!echo listing-start
ls
!echo listing-end
```